# Angular resource 404 Not Found

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-resource

I've read other posts that have similar 404 errors, my problem is that I can correctly query the JSON data, but can't save without getting this error.

I'm using Angular's `$resource` to interact with a JSON endpoint. I have the resource object returning from a factory as follows:

```
app.factory('Product', function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/products.json', { id: '@id' });
});
```

My JSON is valid and I can successfully use resource's `query()` method to return the objects inside of my directive, like this:

```
var item = Product.query().$promise.then(function(promise) {
  console.log(promise) // successfully returns JSON objects
});
```

However, when I try to save an item that I've updated, using the `save()` method, I get a 404 Not Found error.

This is the error that I get:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/products.json/12-34 404 (Not Found)
```

I know that my file path is correct, because I can return the items to update the view. Why am I getting this error and how can I save an item?

Here is my data structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "12-34",
        "name": "Greece",
        "path": "/images/athens.png",
        "description": ""
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: You're sure that a `POST` request should be hitting `products.json/12-34`?

Comment: you get this error because server can't find this file `http://localhost:3000/api/products.json/12-34` and have not route for this

Comment: If I do something like `Product.save({ id: myObject.id })`, and `myObject.id` is equal to `12-34`, and if my data is structured like it is above, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Grundy if I do `Product.save({ id: myObject.id })`, doesn't it return the object *inside* of the JSON file with the matching id? Or is it looking for a file called `12-34`?

Comment: nope, you have simple json file that can't process any query, you should add some server code for process `post`, `put` and other queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `$save` method use the **POST** verb, you will need to figure out which **HTTP verbs** are accepted by your server en order to make an update, most modern api servers accept **PATCH** or **PUT** requests for updating data rather than **POST**.

Then configure your `$resource` instance to use the proper verb like this :

```
app.factory('Product', function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/products.json', { id: '@id' }, {'update': { method:'PUT' }});
});
```

check [$resource docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for more info.

---

**NOTE:** `$resource` is meant to connect a frontend with a backend server supporting RESTful protocol, unless you are using one to receive data & save it into a file rather than a db.
Otherwise if you are only working with frontend solution where you need to implement `$resource` and have no server for the moment, then use a fake one, there is many great solutions out there like [deployd](http://deployd.com).

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't implement POST method for urls like `/api/products.json/12-34`. `POST` method is requested from angular for saving a new resource. So you need to update your server side application to support it and do the actual saving.

Comment: Doesn't angular's resource have the ability to update JSON files from the front-end, how is this done, then?

Comment: @Himmel, angular is client side, it can't update file on server directly

Comment: Angular will send a request to the server application for saving the resource. If the server application don't know how to do it, angular will receive an error.

Comment: Okay so adding a node backend with POST, PUT methods will work to update the JSON file?

Comment: Yes but you need also to do the actual saving unless you have a framework for that.

Comment: using Express, for example?

Comment: Express alone doesn't save to a database. Check links like http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

```
app.factory('Product', function($resource) {
    return $resource('api/products.json/:id', { id: '@id' });
});
```

Try adding "/:id" at the end of the URL string.